# TeeChart .Net - Gridbands on the chart walls

Tags: .net, teechart

I have generated a 3D chart using the TeeChart controls. I am having the following issues with the chart.

1. I tried putting the gridband control on the chart and it works fine on the back wall of the chart. I would like to have the gridband kind of effect (that is one strip white and other strip blue) on the left and the bottom wall of the chart. Is this possible with Teechart?
2. When I generate a bubble chart and set the pointer style to "Polished Sphere", the tooltip is not generated for very small bubbles on the chart.
3. When I generate a bubble chart and set the pointer style to "Polished Sphere", there are certain values which are displayed in the legend, but the corresponding colors for them are not displayed in the legend. In my case, I have 4 bubbles getting plotted on the chart, when I use "Polished Sphere", colors for 2 bubbles are not displayed in the legend.
4. The spacing of the legend symbol and text is not very accurate. It automatically sets less spacing for some text and more for some.

Please help with these issues.

Regards

Nupur Modi

Answer (score 0):

> I tried putting the gridband control on the chart and it works fine on
>   the back wall of the chart. I would like to have the gridband kind of
>   effect (that is one strip white and other strip blue) on the left and
>   the bottom wall of the chart. Is this possible with Teechart?

I am afraid it isn't possible at the moment. I have added it as a future request with number[TF02016509] to will be consider its inclusion to upcoming versions of TeeChartFor.Net.

> When I generate a bubble chart and set the pointer style to "Polished
>   Sphere", the tooltip is not generated for very small bubbles on the
>   chart.

I have reproduced the problem and I have added it in bug list report with number[TF02016510]. We will try to fix it to upcoming maintenance releases of TeeChartFor.Net.

> When I generate a bubble chart and set the pointer style to "Polished
>   Sphere", there are certain values which are displayed in the legend,
>   but the corresponding colors for them are not displayed in the legend.
>   In my case, I have 4 bubbles getting plotted on the chart, when I use
>   "Polished Sphere", colors for 2 bubbles are not displayed in the
>   legend.

I can not reproduce it using last version of TeeChartFor.net build number 4.1.2012.01310. Could you please, tell us which version of teechart are you using? If you don't use latest version I recommend you download the evaluation version that you can find in next link: 
http://www.steema.com/download/net

> The spacing of the legend symbol and text is not very accurate. It
>   automatically sets less spacing for some text and more for some.

I can not reproduce the problem in last version of TeeChartFor.Net using next code:

```
Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bubble bubble1;       
private void InitializeChart()
{
    bubble1 = new Bubble(tChart1.Chart);
    double y = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        y = rnd.Next(100);
        if (i > 0)
        {
            bubble1.Add(i, y, y / i);
        }
        else
        {
            bubble1.Add(i, y, y/y);
        }
    }

    bubble1.Pointer.Style = PointerStyles.PolishedSphere;
}
```

The code have genarate the next image: [image]

Could you tell us if your problem appears in the image?

Thanks,